# python virtualenvwrapper bad interpreter

Tags: python

I recently upgrade from python 3.5 to python 3.6 (with brew on macOS).  However virtualenvwrapper now seems to be broken and I get the error. A reinstall didn't help unfortunately.

```
mkvirtualenv:78: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5: no such file or directory
```

I have `VIRTUALENV_PYTHON=python3` set so the default is to install a virtualenv with python3.

Comment: As a workaround, you can specify path to python interpreter (at least on linux, but it should also work on macOS). Try to call `mkvirtualenv -p PATH_TO_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE NAME_OF_YOUR_ENV`

Comment: I also update python 2 to from python 2.7.10 to  2.7.13 whcih may be the problem rather than python 3.  Launching python via `$ python`.  Give me 2.7.10 rather than the update 2.7.13 so I think it's launching the system python rather than the brew version  `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python` and trying to fix with `brew unlink python && brew link python` doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @Kedrzu mkvirtualenv: command not found

Comment: Note the above comment is no longer relevant as brew has changed the way it installs python and now installs python 2 to `python` and `python2` and python 3 to `python3` commands. This simplifies the issue.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

1. open the terminal 
   use `which python3.6` to show the path of python3.6
2. open the file `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`
3. change the first line which starts with `#!` with the path of python3.6 before

Comment: This does work but will hardcode it to that python version, which isn't ideal when upgrading again later with eg brew on macOS.

Comment: To make this work with all python3.X versions, just use python3 in the path and no specific version. This allows you to `brew switch python 3.X.X` and not having to change the virtualenv file.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because there were spaces in some of the directory names and `virtualenv` did not parse the path correctly. To be safe, just remove spaces from the directory names and replace them with `-` or `_` and it should work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Use: `pip install --upgrade virtualenv`

OR: `sudo pip install -U --force-reinstall virtualenv`